# Как в GIT откатить состояние файла до состояния в stage?

Tags: git

Есть проект, в котором я создал файл `foo.py`. Сделал в нем изменения и применил команду `git add foo.py`. Запустив команду `git status` вижу это(пусть будет ситуация 1):

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   foo.py
```

Я не стал делать коммит, т.е. выполнять команду `git commit` и захотел немного улучшить решение. Другими словами сейчас мой проект находится в таком состоянии(пусть будет ситуация 2):

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   foo.py

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   foo.py
```

Как мне сейчас из ситуации 2 прийти к ситуации 1? То есть убрать изменения из файла `foo.py` , как будто после ситуации 1 я ничего больше не писал.

Comment: Это откатит полностью изменения, в том числе и сделанные в ситуации 1. А мне нужно сохранить в первой ситуации, но убрать из второй.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git checkout foo.py`

Эта команда откатит указанный файл до состояния из индекса.

Найдено на англоязычном SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107789/using-git-how-do-you-reset-the-working-tree-local-file-system-state-to-the-st

Подробности можно найти в официальной документации https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

PS даже сам вывод `git status` подсказывает эту команду.

Comment: Спасибо! Был на все 100% уверен, что `checkout` возвращает к состоянию на момент прошлого комита и по этой причине даже не попроовал

Comment: Аналогично. Сначала погуглил, потом проверил у себя, и только после этого написал.

Answer (score 1):

Команда

```
git checkout -- .
```

Она удаляет все НЕОТСЛЕЖИВАЕМЫЕ изменения. У вас разница между ситуация 1 и ситуация 2 только в том, что появились новые неотслеживаемые изменения. Эта команда их удалит, не трогая отслеживаемые. (Которые стали отслеживаемыми, когда вы выполнили команду add при ситуации 1).